# Validate XML file with XSD file that is referenced inside of XML document in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am attempting to create a class that will validate an XML file that contains a namespace and schemaLocation. I got the following code to run and most likely as it is supposed to.

My XML documents will have a

```
<Root xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile" 
    xmlns:efile="http://www.irs.gov/efile" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.irs.gov/efile \\network\\path\\to\\file.xsd">
```

I am validating it with the following code:

```
public bool Validate(string xml){
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;            
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(_xml), settings);
    using(reader){
        while(reader.Read());
    }
}

private void ValidationCallback(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args){
//I add the args to a property
}
```

This processes the file fine, but it is not validating it the way it needs to be. It should be referencing the XSD file in the schemaLocation (I have ensured that this works in other tools, it finds and validates the file properly).

However, I get this or a similar warning for every node in the XML file:

> Message = "Could not find schema information for the element 'http://www.irs.gov/efile:nodeName'."

I have also tried changing the XML text at runtime to locate the XSD file via a URL (there is a URL that is not on the network), but it was the same result.

**Edit**

After some more testing I really hammered that the thought that it is just not loading the XSD file correctly.

I have then attempted several things that inevitably ended in a slightly different but just as vague error:

> Type 'http://www.irs.gov/efile:StringType' is not declared, or is not a simple type.'

I think it is loading the initial xsd file, but inside there are several (by several I mean around 600 counting only the 2nd level) other references, all in the same file structure not on the servers drive.

I then tried to use this implementation:

```
public bool Validate(string xml){
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;            
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
    settings.XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();

    XmlReader xsdReader = XmlReader.Create(@"\\network\path\to\file.xsd");
    using(xsdReader){
        settings.Schemas.Add(nameSpace, xsdReader); //namespace is grabbed earlier in the method, it is accurate to the XML file
    }
    settings.Schemas.Compile(); //The same error is thrown here

    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(_xml), settings);
    using(reader){
        while(reader.Read());
    }
}
```

This leads to the exact same error on the method call

```
settings.Schemas.Compile();
```

I also tried overloading the GetEntity and ResolveUri methods in the XmlUrlResolver class, and the ResolveUri and GetEntity methods are called one time with the network path I gave it

> \\network\path\to\file.xsd

**Edit**

I am using .NET core. a quick discovery just told me that the schemas read and compiled in Regular .Net (? not sure what to call it to differentiate).

How can I get this to work in .NET Core?

Comment: Both codes won't even compile. Please don't write the code here on this site. Use an IDE and post the real code that will compile.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I adjusted it to compile as best as I could using Visual Studios. The code was written in an IDE but I formatted it poorly, and when revised, removed some stuff on accident, sorry.

Comment: Anyone coming in to read this please note the edit at the bottom of the question. When this code is run in a normal .NET environment it runs as expected. So if you are using .NET Core, this is possibly the issue.